# Using Dropzone inside a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, upload, dropzone

First: this is not a duplicate question, as I didn't find any answer that is working out there.

I am trying to use Dropzonejs inside a form, the [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically) is not working, also; all answers out there is not working too.

I need a working example, as I have tried so many examples and answers without any luck to get it to work.

Please advise.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="action" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" class="dropzone">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="dropClickable">
            Drop Your File here...!!
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            init: function () {
                // Do your update and process stuff
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Also; tried this example, and got nothing to work:

https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

And that's what I get:

[image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what didn't work :)

Comment: Lol what do you mean the documentation is not working? Cmon man you have 1.1k rep and you know how much we hate "its not working"

Comment: @LioraHaydont, edited.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript, I am sorry man, but I am really frustrated from that library and answers out there, just updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Dropzone stuff is executing before the browser finished loading.

Wrap your javascript with `window.onload = function() {` or `$(function() {`

```
<script>     
$(function() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            init: function () {
                // Do your update and process stuff
            }
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

With those changes the code now works on my machine; using jquery 3.3.1 and latest Dropzone

For your second example;
Let's open up dev tools (F12) and go to debug, we see:
`Error: No URL provided.`
Clicking into the line tells us why...

```
 if (_this.options.url == null) {
  _this.options.url = _this.element.getAttribute("action");
}

if (!_this.options.url) {
  throw new Error("No URL provided.");
}
```

So if we set (in the `<form>`) `action= "test.php"` the page now works.

Comment: Thanks, that's working with first code I mentioned, but not with second link: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Comment: @CairoCoder Updated with solution to the second code.

Comment: Thanks man, you made my day. I was searching out there for a solution,  no one but you could catch it. that would help a lot of developers. :)